# R conditional logic embedded within calc function for raster

Tags: raster, r

I am trying to create a new raster from one existing raster using conditional logic, `ifelse` statements. The existing raster has numeric values and NA values. Here is what I tried so far, based on other posts within Stack Exchange:

```
f <- function(phos_all) {
        ifelse(is.na(phos_all) | NA, 
          ifelse(phos_all<=4,30,
            ifelse(phos_all>=4) & (phos_all<10), 20,
              ifelse((phos_all>=10),0)))
}

phos_fert_2.5 <- calc(phos_all, fun = f, na.rm = TRUE)
```

When I run this code I get the following error:

> Error in .calcTest(x[1:5], fun, na.rm, forcefun, forceapply) : 
>     cannot use this function. Perhaps add '...' or 'na.rm' to the function arguments?

Comment: What do you mean with `is.na(phos_all) | NA`? This is saying the same thing (NA == TRUE or NA) and there is no resulting condition. You can deal with elements that do not meet any condition by having the last condition in the nested `ifelse` statments be NA, which would include existing NA values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start with your `ifelse` statement. You have `is.na(phos_all) | NA` stating the condition `[NA == TRUE or NA]` which is redundant and can be dealt with at the end if the `ifelse`. You also have some misplaced/unnecessary parenthesis.

Let's clarify the `f` reclassification function a bit.

```
f <- function(x, ...) { 
    ifelse(x <= 4, 30,
      ifelse(x >= 4 & x < 10, 20,
        ifelse(x >= 10, 0, NA )))
  }
```

Now we can test it on a vector to make sure it is yielding expected results.

```
y <- round(runif(100, 0, 20))
  y[c(2,50,90)] <- NA 
f(y)
```

We can now roll it into a raster example. Note that I did add a `...` argument into the `f` function. This can sometimes help `calc` and `overlay` with passing the function.

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(nrow=100, ncol=100)
  r[] <- round(runif(ncell(r), 0, 20)) 

( rrc <- calc(r, fun = f) )
    unique(rrc[])
```